# Attempt get html content from url always returns "Connection timed out" in NetBeans IDE

Tags: java

Good afternoon,

I'm trying get html content from specific url, but the return is always "Connection timed out". Why? Someone can help me please? Thanks in advance.

Here is code used:

```
public static String getContentResult() throws IOException{

    URL url = new URL("http://ip1.dynupdate.no-ip.com/");
    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    byte [] buffer = new byte[256];

    while(true){
        int byteRead = in.read(buffer);
        if(byteRead == -1)
            break;
        for(int i = 0; i < byteRead; i++){
            sb.append((char)buffer[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  System.out.println(getContentResult());
    }
```

Comment: works for me as expected, something must be messed up in your network.

Comment: Like @MightyPork said, your code works. It's either firewall blocking or the program behaves like DoS attack so the network blocks your request. It could also be too many requests at the same time that caused the timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing some basic debug for instance try connecting to another page and doing the same, but I strongly believe it is some of your computers settings like antivirus, firewall or any network filtering that is going on on your network. Is there a proxy?

Also if a adage is big enough, you might face problems with your bufer, personally I keep it like 512 or 1024 to be on the safe side.

Good luck

Comment: My personal firewall, was the cause of the problem. Thank you to all!

Comment: Anytime =] happy to help